# Ошибка HTTP 500

Tags: php, .htaccess

Настраиваю сайт.Есть файл-инсталлятор,в котором необходимо прописать доступ к БД,после ввода всех данных должно перенаправить на файл addbot.php,в котором необходимо настроить данные о боте,но вместо этого пишет Ошибка HTTP 500.Возможно проблема в файле .htaccess,но не могу понять где именно.Файлы прилагаются ниже.Заранее большое спасибо

installer.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['database'])){
$host = $_POST['host'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $sql = file_get_contents('csgo.sql');
$qr = $conn->exec($sql);
$fname = "../config/config.php";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
$content = str_replace("#dbhost#", "$host", $content);
$content = str_replace("#dbuser#", "$username", $content);
$content = str_replace("#dbpassword#", "$password", $content);
$content = str_replace("#dbname#", "$dbname", $content);
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);

include_once('../classes/phpmailer/api/api-debug.php');
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
/*

*/
header('URL=../installation/addbot.php');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title >CSGO ROULETTE V2 INSTALLER</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="The most exclusive CS:GO betting platform with unique games &amp; a excellent community.">
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="/template/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center"><b>CSGO ROULETTE INSTALLER V2 By Lobster</b></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Important!</strong> Add your database connection cardinals !
</div>
<form  action="" id="form" method="post">
<div class="form-inline">
<input class="form-control" onkeyup='check()' id="installerinput" type="text" name="host" placeholder="host"/>
<input class="form-control" onkeyup='check()' id="installerinput" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name" />
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
<input class="form-control" onkeyup='check()' id="installerinput" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" />
<input class="form-control" onkeyup='check()' id="installerinput" type="text" name="dbname" placeholder="dbname"/>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-installer" name="database" type="submit" disabled>NEXT STEP</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
    var count = 0, attr = "disabled", $sub = $("#btn-installer"), $inputs = $("input[type=text]");  
    $inputs.each(function(){
        count += ($.trim($(this).val())) ? 1:0;
    });
    (count >= $inputs.length ) ? $sub.removeAttr(attr):$sub.attr(attr,attr);       
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

addbot.php

```
<?php
include_once ('../config/config.php');
if (isset($_POST['addbot'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
  $steamid = $_POST['steamid'];
  $shared_secret = $_POST['shared_secret'];
  $identity_secret = $_POST['identity_secret'];
  $accountName = $_POST['accountName'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `bots`(name, steamid, shared_secret, identity_secret, accountName, password) VALUES (:name, :steamid, :shared_secret, :identity_secret, :accountName, :password)";
  $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $query->execute( array(':name'=>$name, ':steamid'=>$steamid, ':shared_secret'=>$shared_secret, ':identity_secret'=>$identity_secret, ':accountName'=>$accountName, ':password'=>$password));
  header('Refresh: 1; URL=../installation/data.php');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title >CSGO ROULETTE V1 INSTALLER</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="The most exclusive CS:GO betting platform with unique games &amp; a excellent community.">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="/template/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading text-center"><b>ADD BOTS</b></div>
 <div class="panel-body">
 <form class="form-group text-center" method="post">
                <div class="form-inline">
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="steamid" placeholder="SteamID" />
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="accountName" placeholder="Account Name" />
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="shared_secret" placeholder="Shared secret" />
                <input style="width:45%; margin-top: 2px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="identity_secret" placeholder="Identity secret" />
                </div>
                 <button style="width:90%; margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="btn-bot" type="submit" name="addbot" disabled>Next Step</button>
                </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function(){
    var count = 0, attr = "disabled", $sub = $("#btn-bot"), $inputs = $("input[type=text]");  
    $inputs.each(function(){
        count += ($.trim($(this).val())) ? 1:0;
    });
    (count >= $inputs.length ) ? $sub.removeAttr(attr):$sub.attr(attr,attr);       
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|



order allow,deny
deny from 46.101.200.204
allow from all
```

Comment: Смотрите error.log Апача или виртуального хоста.

Comment: как  посмотреть error.log ?

Comment: Напишите, какую операционную систему используете.